# What logging scopes are available out of the box?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to include the fully qualified URL of the request when logging something. If available I want to use an event logging scope (context property in serilog) like `{RequestUrl}` in my logging template. How do I know if there is already a property available that I can use or if I have to do this manually?

I know of the following properties:

```
ActionId 
ActionName // Like ActionId from aspnet/Mvc (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcCoreLoggerExtensions.ActionLogScope ) 
Level // Gives the level e.g. Warning
RequestId // Can be used for event correlation
RequestPath // Like RequestId from aspnet/Hosting (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingLoggerExtensions.HostingLogScope)
SourceContext // Probably from serilog. Gives the TCategoryName of the ILogger e.g. MyNamespace.MyController
```

Where is an overview of all the properties supported by default during a request? Or is it possible to get all available properties at runtime?

Comment: Official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#scopes) don't mention much...

Comment: If you have Seq hooked up, you can run `select names() from stream` to get a distinct list of properties that have been logged. Not sure if this helps, but not much else I can think of. Good luck!

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt Unfortunately I don't use Seq :( Maybe someone who uses it can give the full list of properties.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use @ operator in front of context to tells Serilog to serialize the object passed in.

```
_logger.LogInformation("{@context}!", context);
```

Comment: Sorry, but my question isn't about how to serialize something with Serilog.